# Using sequelize with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, sequelize.js

So I'm having some issues trying to use sequelize with AWS Lambda, when  querying a table where id = 1 it sometimes returns me data and sometimes it doesn't. I read that Sequelize connections and AWS Lambda service don't get well each other because of the how Lambda executes a function.

My question is, is it not enough to open a connection at the top of a function and then close it at the bottom (before returning something)? If not, what else can I do?

Update:

```js
const findCityByPk = async (pathParameters) => {
    const { Postgresql: ps } = require('../libs/utils/potsgresql');
    console.log(ps.connection.connectionManager);
    const { id } = pathParameters;
    try {
        const city = await City.findByPk(id);
        if (city) {
            ps.connection.close();
            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(city)
            };
        }
        ps.connection.close();
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'City not found`' })
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        await ps.connection.close();
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify(err)
        };
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm testing it sometimes returns me the correct object from my table
`{"id":"1","city_name":"Lima2","zip_code":"12312","time_zone_utc":-5}` -> this is what is supposed to be returning, and instead I'm getting this object

```js
{
    "requestTime": "06/Dec/2021:18:07:24 +0000",
    "requestId": "8b5bf017-c180-41cc-9de6-b07599f0e9b8",
    "apiId": "xx",
    "resourceId": "xx",
    "resourcePath": "/city/{id}",
    "path": "/dev/city/1",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "status": "500",
    "authLatency": "-",
    "integrationLatency": "48",
    "integrationStatus": "200",
    "responseLatency": "50",
    "responseLength": "2",
    "errorMessage": "-",
    "format": "SLS_ACCESS_LOG",
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

And also, this is how it's being made the connection

```js
const createConnection = () => {
    console.info("[Postgresql] createConnection: start")

    console.info("[Postgresql] createConnection: creating conection start")
    let conn;
    let string_connection;
    try {
        string_connection = `postgres://${config.DB_USER}:${config.DB_PASSWORD}@${config.DB_HOST}:5432/${config.DB_NAME}`
        //console.debug(`[Postgresql] string_connection: ${string_connection}`)
        conn = new Sequelize(string_connection, { logging: false, pool: { max: 1, min: 0, idle: 1000 } });
    } catch (e) {
        console.debug(`[Postgresql] createConnection: creating conection error ${string_connection}`)
        throw e;
    }
    console.info("[Postgresql] createConnection:creating conection  end")
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: More details are needed. You should also post some code.

Comment: @kgiannakakis I updated my question

Comment: If `ps.connection.close` is really async then why you call it twice in the code w/o `await`?

Comment: I want to close the connection in some use cases: if there is an error, if no city was found and when a city was found. But the problem is not from that `await` before the ps.connection.close() because in theory the connection should close automatically when lambda function ends. I was just testing that `ps.connection.close()` to see if that could solve the problem from having multiple connections. But even with or withour closing the connection manually solves it.

Comment: Also, I'm not getting an error when testing locally. This only happens when I make a request to the endpoint in the cloud

Comment: Is it necessary to close connection when you have pool parameters ?